# Retrieve parent and children with connect by

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g

I have the following query:

```
  SELECT *
  FROM ORGANIZATION_TABLE
  START WITH PARENT_ID       = 6
  CONNECT BY PRIOR   CHILD_ID = PARENT_ID;
```

This query brings all the children for parent with ID 6. My question is if it possible to have a query that returns both the children of the parent with ID 6 but also the parent it self in the same result set.

Comment: Would you please share table structure, current result and expected result?

Comment: Possibly you just need `start with child_id = 6`, but without sample data it's not going to be easy to say.

Comment: That was easy after all.  I was struggling with many other workarounds. Yes START WITH CHILD_ID did the trick. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Boneist - `START WITH child_id = 6` can resolve the issue
see sample below

```
with ORGANIZATION_TABLE as
(select 1 as parent_id, 0 as child_id from dual union all
 select null as parent_id, 6 as child_id from dual union all
 select 6 as parent_id, 61 as child_id from dual union all
 select 6 as parent_id, 62 as child_id from dual union all
 select 6 as parent_id, 63 as child_id from dual union all
 select 63 as parent_id, 631 as child_id from dual union all
 select 63 as parent_id, 632 as child_id from dual union all
 select 631 as parent_id, 6311 as child_id from dual union all
 select 7 as parent_id, 0 as child_id from dual 
) 
SELECT *
  FROM ORGANIZATION_TABLE
  START WITH child_id       = 6
  CONNECT BY PRIOR   CHILD_ID = PARENT_ID;


1       6
2   6   61
3   6   62
4   6   63
5   63  631
6   631 6311
7   63  632
```